# graphql java: global dataFetcher and dynamic object

Tags: java, graphql, graphql-java

I'm trying to use GraphQL like client of a REST API. My backend return JSON but in my application client i write graphQL and in client i translate graphQL queries to HTTP call's.

My schema:

```
type Query {
   students: [Student]
}
type Student {
   name: String
}
```

POJO example:

```
public class Student {
    private Integer id;
    private String name;
}
```

My resolver:

```
public class Query implements GraphQLQueryResolver {
  public List<Post> students() {
    // HTTP Request
   }
}
```

In all library's implementations i need create a POJO for Student and write a resolver for request in my API.

A way exist to don't need create a POJO and a create global execute resolver?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using libraries like graphql-java-tools (which seems to be the case), you need POJOs, as this is where the library gets its type mappings from. But if you're just using graphql-java itself, you can wire it any way you like - including having a single global resolver (i.e. `DataFetcher`).

For an idea how to do this, see http://graphql-java.readthedocs.io/en/latest/schema.html#idl

You want something like:

```
SchemaParser schemaParser = new SchemaParser();
SchemaGenerator schemaGenerator = new SchemaGenerator();

File schemaFile = loadSchema("yourStudentSchema.graphqls");

TypeDefinitionRegistry typeRegistry = schemaParser.parse(schemaFile);
RuntimeWiring wiring = buildRuntimeWiring();
GraphQLSchema graphQLSchema = schemaGenerator.makeExecutableSchema(typeRegistry, wiring);
```

RuntimeWiring is where you hook the resolvers, e.g:

```
RuntimeWiring buildRuntimeWiring() {
    return RuntimeWiring.newRuntimeWiring()
            // this uses builder function lambda syntax
            .type("Query", typeWiring -> typeWiring
                    .dataFetcher("students", env -> fetchDataSomeHow(env)))             
            .build();
}
```

So you can provide the same `DataFetcher` implementation to each `dataFetcher` call f that's what you're after. graphql-java itself makes no assumptions about way it's wired and implemented, e.g. it does not enforce POJOs or anything else.

Comment: Thanks by response... My solution is little different of your suggestion but in resume is equal... For don't write pojo my solution was create a single graphql type (e.g ``` restCall() { data } ```)

Comment: @Renan Aren't you sacrificing most of the benefits of GraphQL that way?

Comment: a little, but this way served very well for this service ... For you have context , I put this service in production after this solution ... I know i lost typesafe in entities (e.g `student {}`), but still have a typesafe of fields... This service is a client of a api for generate / create custom report by the users and render (e.g user create report with mark entities what he wants after choose a user and request a report then create a queries in graphql to print this report)

Comment: I don't know if you know Scala... But I searched in Scala this way appeared a little more safe ... you can create in compile time / maybe with macros a schema and "pojo's"... but i not sure